# Use data from Mysql to ElasticSearch with Logstash

Tags: mysql, configuration, export, elasticsearch

I'm using logstash for use my mysql database in ElasticSearch

My conf is the next.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://[ip]:3306/nextline_dev"
        jdbc_user => "[user]"
        jdbc_password => "[pass]"
        #schedule => "* * * * *"
        #jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/path/mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM Account"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "account"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    }
}
```

But I have some questions, I want to schedule more than one query, but the index will be always account.

Can I make a dynamic index for the output to elasticsearch? And how can I use more than one statement? (Export more than one table)

Answer (score 0):

I found that ELK LogStash 6.X have document_id deprecated, so if I use my configuration without document_id it works.